# Overwritting function identifiers while registering identifiers (difference between var and let?)

Tags: javascript, closures, identifier

I'm currently reading the book *Secrets of the Javascript Ninja* and I do not understand the following behaviour based on an example from chapter 5 explaining how function identifiers are overwritten:

code example from the book:

```
console.log(typeof fun);

var fun = 3;

console.log(typeof fun);

function fun() {}

console.log(typeof fun);
```

Output as expected: function / number / number

```
console.log(typeof fun);

let fun = 3;

console.log(typeof fun);

function fun() {}

console.log(typeof fun);
```

But when I change the definition to `let` I get the error that fun has already been decleared. When the lexical environment is created why can I override `var` but `let` already blocks the definition of the function declaration?

The attached question, was also answered with "`let` variables are not initialized until their definition is evaluated."
[What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: That was pretty much a basic reason for the introduction of `let`.

Comment: "*let variables are not initialized until their definition is evaluated.*" - yes, but that's irrelevant here. The important part of the answer you linked is "*var will let you re-declare the same variable in the same scope while let raises a SyntaxError.*"